# How to process the input?

Tags: java, swt

Hello this is my first post here and I am doing my best to learn programming!
I am trying to make a program with SWT, in Eclipse. 
It's a basic program that's supposed to receive input from a user and depending (`if` statement) on what day the user inputs, show a certain output.

THE PROBLEM: I first tried to put the `if` statement under the text field, but I noticed I needed some sort of button that makes this run, or else it didn't work!

Where is the error that makes the input: `Dilluns` not  output:`MATESSS!`?

```
public void open() {
    Display display = Display.getDefault();
    createContents();
    elsllibres.open();
    elsllibres.layout();
    while (!elsllibres.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
}

protected void createContents() {
    elsllibres = new Shell();
    elsllibres.setSize(450, 300);
    elsllibres.setText("OSKARITOOO Industries");

    Label lblQuinsLlibresCal = new Label(elsllibres, SWT.NONE);
    lblQuinsLlibresCal.setBounds(10, 10, 360, 15);
    lblQuinsLlibresCal.setText("QUINS LLIBRES CAL PORTAR AVUI?");

    Label lblIndicaElDia = new Label(elsllibres, SWT.NONE);
    lblIndicaElDia.setBounds(10, 31, 96, 15);
    lblIndicaElDia.setText("INDICA EL DIA:");

    text_1 = new Text(elsllibres, SWT.BORDER);
    text_1.setText("EX: Dilluns, Dimarts...");
    text_1.setBounds(10, 52, 123, 21);

    Label info = new Label(elsllibres, SWT.NONE);
    info.setBounds(10, 79, 174, 15);
    info.setText("Cal portar els llibres de...");

    resultat = new Label(elsllibres, SWT.NONE);
    resultat.setBounds(10, 100, 207, 15);

    Button ok = new Button(elsllibres, SWT.NONE);
    ok.addTouchListener(new TouchListener() {
        public void touch(TouchEvent arg0) {
            String quediaes;
             quediaes = text_1.toString();
            if(quediaes.equals("Dilluns")){
                resultat.setText("MATESSSS!");
            }
        }
    });
    ok.setBounds(142, 48, 75, 25);
    ok.setText("OK");


    text_1.addMouseTrackListener(new MouseTrackAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseEnter(org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseEvent e) {
            text_1.setText("");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This isn't Swing. Its SWT.

Comment: upsitubsy! I got confused sorry

Comment: In that case I’m sorry I approved an edit substituting swt tag with swing. Instead, the title and text should have been changed to read SWT. That went too fast.

Comment: Yep, had I seen @camickr 's comment I would've included those changes in my edit. Feel free to edit over it.

Answer (score 0):

Your are using a touch listener which requires a device which supports touch (and also must be enabled).

Assuming you are using a normal PC you need to use a selection listener for the button:

```
Button ok = new Button(elsllibres, SWT.NONE);
ok.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter()
  {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e)
    {
      String quediaes = text_1.getText();  // getText not toString

      if (quediaes.equals("Dilluns")) {
         resultat.setText("MATESSSS!");
    }
  }
});
```

You must also call the `getText()` method of the text control, the `toString` method you are using does not return the input text.